# setup database for codeIgniter ErrorException [ 8192 ]: mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I downloaded a codeIgniter project from server and I tried to run it on my localhost, I am not really familiar with PHP,Mysql, I used different advice in stackoverflow and google to set up the environment but stil I have some errors, I appreciated if you can help me for in set up!

I used MAMP as a local server

Here is my error:

[image]

Here is my database.php

```
$active_group = ENVIRONMENT;
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['development']['hostname'] = 'mysqli:host=localhost';
$db['development']['username'] = 'root';
$db['development']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['development']['database'] = 'test';
$db['development']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['development']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['development']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['development']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['development']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['development']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['development']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['development']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';


$db['staging']['hostname'] = 'mysqli:host=localhost';
$db['staging']['username'] = 'mgr';
$db['staging']['password'] = 'test';
$db['staging']['database'] = 'bmg';
$db['staging']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['staging']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['staging']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['staging']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['staging']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['staging']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['staging']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['staging']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Here is mysqli_driver.php

```
function escape_str($str, $like = FALSE)
    {
        if (is_array($str))
        {
            foreach ($str as $key => $val)
            {
                $str[$key] = $this->escape_str($val, $like);
            }

            return $str;
        }

        if (function_exists('mysqli_real_escape_string') AND is_object($this->conn_id))
        {
            $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn_id, $str);
        }
        elseif (function_exists('mysql_real_escape_string'))
        {
            $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        }
        else
        {
            $str = addslashes($str);
        }

        if ($like === TRUE)
        {
            $str = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\\%', '\\_'), $str);
        }

        return $str;
    }
```

Appreciated any Help.

Update

Here is the list of extensions

```
; Extensions

;extension=apcu.so

extension=imap.so
extension=yaz.so
extension=mcrypt.so
extension=gettext.so
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
I added -> extension=pdo_mysqli.so

;extension=imagick.so
;extension=tidy.so
;extension=oauth.so
```

I checked my php info and I saw mysqli enable

[image]

but in my folder I do not have any mysql.sock

[image]

Comment: Instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string` you are using `mysql_real_escape_string` which is deprecated. Check that you have mysqli extension enabled or mysqli is in the settings of the framework, not a mysql.

Comment: @Cheery how can I check it, in which file?php.ini?

Comment: To check that you have this extension - `<?php phpinfo();?>` and look at the output. It looks like it is not enabled, that is why framework is switching to mysql. To enable - check extensions list in php.ini (if you have Windows). With *nix it is slightly different.

Comment: Try to add `extension=pdo_mysqli.so` and restart server. I do not know if this module comes by default in mamp

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo();` for mysqli extension. disable mysql for sure. Check that you modifying the correct file with settings. From the screenshot it is obvious that the wrong extensions is used. Also, in your config, try to change `mysql:host=localhost` to `mysqli:host=localhost`

Answer (score 0):

You can updated in CodeIgniter as follows:

```
    $db = get_instance()->db->conn_id;
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $secrectKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$data->secrectKey);
```